# adodc Visual Basic 6 Access 2010

Tags: vb6

I have made an application using VB6 and it’s already connected to an Access database.

Everything works perfectly: I have my table field shown in my VB application as it should be. My problem is that I don't know how to link between filed that is contain (yes/no) in Access with option botton in VB. I have them in frame but that’s all. Any help or code or even something to start with it.

Here’s a picture:

[image]

In the picture you will notice that it’s already (yes) but that is what VB6 gives me; it's suppose to be no anyway.

Comment: If it's a boolean, why not use a Checkbox instead?

Answer (score 0):

Option button is not a databound control. You will need to work directly with it's events and the data control to update or reflect the changes.

Another user has already suggested using a checkbox control, which IS a databound control.

Either way shouldn't prove too difficult, but the checkbox should be near plug and play.